# Why elasticsearch returns too different results for the same query on different indices?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl

I first use Elasticsearch & Kibana so please keep calm with my question!

I was given an ES that already had an index called `dai-*` having some data pre-ingested. To safely play around with the ES I created a new index called `ad-prior`. I then continued feeding the both indices with data looking like:

```
{'obj_id': 'UHDRXEWEEK', 'event_type': 'PREC_AD_STARTED', 'event_id': '5c6b584373d', 'timestamp': 1550540223736L, 'channel_id': '123456789'}
{'obj_id': 'FDREJJSSHE', 'event_type': 'PREC_AD_STARTED', 'event_id': '4f53jhabd24', 'timestamp': 1550540225872L, 'channel_id': '123456789'}
```

I then tried doing searches on Kibana's Discover:

```
event_type.keyword:PREC_AD_STARTED
event_type:PREC_AD_STARTED
event_type:'PREC_AD_STARTED'
```

Index `dai-*`: the above searches all returned `367 hits`.

Index `ad-prior`: the above searches returned different results: `event_type:PREC_AD_STARTED` returning `8 hits` but the two others returning `0 hits`.

Why did the above searches return the same result for `dai-*` while return different results for `ad-prior`?

**Update**

To answer @Nishant Saini's comment I have grabbed what-I-suppose-to-be mapping for `event_type` here:

For `dai-*`:

```
"event_type": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
}
```

For `ad-prior`:

```
"event_type": {
  "type": "keyword",
  "ignore_above": 1024
}
```

Comment: `dai-*` uses wildcard hence targeting all indexes starting with **dia-**. Is mapping of new index `ad-prior` same as for those `dia-*`?

Comment: @NishantSaini I added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Case 1: `event_type.keyword:PREC_AD_STARTED`

In index `dia-*` the property `event_type` has a [sub-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) named `keyword`. The above query refer to this sub-field i.e. `event_type.keyword`. For the match in `dai-*` the documents are returned, whereas this sub-field is not present for field `event_type` in index `ad-prior` and hence no results.

#### Case 2: `event_type:PREC_AD_STARTED`

event_type is present in both indexes. Even though in index `dai-*` the data type is `text` and since by default standard analyzer is applied theredore `PREC_AD_STARTED` will result in `prec_ad_started`. The above query applies same analyzer to input string which also then translates to `prec_ad_started` and hence matches to documents.

In case of index `ad-prior` the data type of `event_type` is `keyword` and hence input string is indexed as is. Even while searching the same happens and hence the query above matches in this case as well.

Therefore this query gives you result in case of both indexes.

#### Case 3: `event_type:'PREC_AD_STARTED'`

For index `dai-*` as query is on field `event_type` (not on event_type.keyword) which is of type `text` (default analyzer: standard) when `PREC_AD_STARTED` is indexed the value that get indexed is `prec_ad_started` due to [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). The query above is searching for `'PREC_AD_STARTED'` (with single quotes). Even this string will be passed through standard analyzer which also translates to `prec_ad_started` and hence this query matches.

In case of `ad-prior` index, `event_type` is of type `keyword`, which means index as is without any modification. Since we are querying on field `event_type` the query will apply no analyzer (since data type is [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/keyword.html)) and hence will search for `'PREC_AD_STARTED'` (not `PREC_AD_STARTED`) and hence no matches.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! A side question: Is there a way to force `ad-prior` having the same mapping as `dai-*`? Or even a way to copy the mapping from `dai-*` to `ad-prior`?

Comment: You can use `GET <index_name>/_mappings` to get mappings of index and then use `PUT <new_index>` to create index with the mapping you get from get mapping api.

Comment: Also please accept/upvote if the answer is cleared your doubt :)

Comment: Yeah, will do both :D